# Find frameworks which aren't being used in your project

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I want to get rid of all the useless frameworks that are added in my project. Is there an easy way to tell which frameworks are being used and which are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove them all. Compile and read the linker errors. You may have to add them back a few at a time but you are guaranteed to only add back the required ones.

Answer (score 1):

Remove one by one and compile...

Make sure you have a backup of your project :)

if any linking error comes, re add that and follow the step one with another :)